# Xcode 5.1 can not work with device of iPhone 7.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The Xcode 5.1 suppport arm64 architecture.
Howerer there is some third-party libraries that can only build for 32.
After updated to Xocode 5.1 , my project get some errors in the third-party libraries while I would see when I use the 64 bit simulator.
Now I just can not debug my app with my iphone 5s,which is annoyance.
Any one got the same situation?

Answer (score 1):

edit Architectures, remove the default and add armv7, then add armv7s.

The issue is that Xcode 5.1 redefines standard architecture to include arm64 which is often not available with third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue happen to me when I connected my iPhone AFTER upgrading to Mavericks (10.9.3) AND after XCode (5.1.1) had already been launched.  The iPhone did not show up in the available schemes.  I exited the XCode app and relaunched it.  The app then re-read the symbols from the phone and the device then showed up in the scheme.